# FormMaximised event not firing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method that should fire on the maximize button being clicked, or the form being resized:

```
private void CableID_QueryView_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormWindowState LastWindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    if (this.WindowState != LastWindowState)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            //do stuff
    }
}
```

However, the event isn't being fired. Specifically the

```
if (this.WindowState != LastWindowState)
```

Does it make a difference if the form is a child form?

Comment: Are you sure the event is hooked up correctly? Have you set a breakpoint? Is the first line getting called? What is that actual value of `this.WindowsState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put it in `SizeChanged` event.

Comment: That did it. For some reason it gets called twice though?

Comment: I did. But I'm saying in the debugger, the `SizeChanged` event gets called twice regardless when I maximise the form

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure what you mean by debugger, but I just ran your code and it gets fired exactly one time.

Comment: Incredibly odd... When I run it, I placed a breakpoint on the first line of the `SizeChanged` method, it ran normally, then immediately ran again, as if it had resized it twice. On restore it only fires once, and if I resize the form by clicking and dragging, it fires once. I got rid of the `Resize` method all together, to the same effect.

Comment: If you only have this problem in pause mode, it's not a big deal. When visual studio stops the program, messages sent to the program's window can get repeated because of sudden moves caused by visual studio.

Comment: I added a `Console.WriteLine("Hi")` in the function, and it's getting fired twice. I tested this in the .exe. It appears to be firing once when the form is maximised, then again when the `//do stuff` happens

Comment: @Ben I don't know what your overall code is, but the code provided in this question runs normally. There might be some other code that causes this kind of behavior.